# Are questions related to ereader technology off-site?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

To me, [this](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/963/how-electronic-ink-display-retains-the-particles-on-top-of-micro-capsule) question seems to be off topic for ebooks SE (the user also asked [a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99673/how-electrophoretic-display-like-e-ink-retains-particles-on-top-of-capsule-witho) on the physics se). What are your thoughts for questions related to the technology behind ereaders? On or off topic?

I'm on the fence for this one. We allow some questions about ebooks and the underlying technology. Should we do the same for ereaders? It may open up the site for more activity. The site, however, is ebooks SE, not ereaders SE. Perhaps where we can be lenient towards ebook technology, we cannot show the same leniency for ereaders.

Comment: I agree that that particular question would be better suited for Physics.SE.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that this is off-topic at least for the particular question mentioned. I've closed the question. We can further discuss this if more ereader tech questions come up.

Answer (score 4):

I think that technology questions are on topic, though as in this case a better answer is more likely at a different site.  Each question can be examined on a case by case bases until we get enough volume on the topic to make a better judgement.

In the example given the question has an accepted answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99673 so it should be closed here, for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think that ebook technology and ereader operation are about as far as we should allow the site to stretch. Science and technology of ereaders should be off topic.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it should depend on whether the device tech question is asked with a view to answering a specifically ebook-related question. Asking how eInk screens work in order to determine if they were suitable for a multimedia ebook that included video, for example, would be fine. More general questions about how the devices work, such as the one referenced, seem like they'd be better suited for a different site.